# EntityManager.merge() on same object doesn't include all mapping of second

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

When I add GameObjectives to its parent (whether another GameObjective or a Game itself) and call EntityManager.merge(parent) the GameObjective and UserGameObjective get added to the database (MySQL) no problem.

But When I add another GameObjective to the same parent and call the merge again, the GameObjective gets added but the UserGameObjective doesn't.

If I close the program and add another GameObjective to the same parent, the new GameObjective and UserGameObjective both get added again.

Does anyone see what the problem is?

**GameObjective**

```
@Entity
public class GameObjective extends IEntityUser<UserGameObjective> implements Serializable{

@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Game game;
@JoinColumn(nullable = true)
@ManyToOne
private GameObjective parent;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private List<GameObjective> objectives;
...
```

**IEntityUser**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IEntityUser<T extends UserEntity> extends IEntity{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity")
    protected List<T> userEntities;
    ...
```

**UserEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(UserEntityId.class)
public abstract class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
    ...
```

**UserGameObjective**

```
@Entity
public class UserGameObjective extends UserEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gameObjectiveId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private GameObjective entity;
    ...
```

**UserEntityId**

```
public class UserEntityId implements Serializable{

    private int user;
    private int entity;
    ...
```

Comment: `GameObjective` is your parent table ?

Comment: GameObjective holds the primary key of Game and its parent.

**GameObjective**: https://d.pr/FREE/XFe1VA
**UserGameObjective**: https://d.pr/FREE/tLByKB